# How to compare the regex inside substitution expression to a variable in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

So I'm new to Perl and I'm trying **regex**:

```
my $address = 'http://mail.google.com/belmark';

s/$address=~(\w+:\/\/)(.*.com)(\/\w+)/$1$2\/dev\/public_html/ if ($address =~ /.*\/belmark/);
```

That code gives me error in the substitution part

What I want to accomplish is use a pre-defined variable for comparison in regex inside substitution expression. I can successfully compare it using the `$_`. So how do i do it?

Comment: Don't you mean `$address =~ s/...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $address = 'http://mail.google.com/belmark';

$address =~ s/(\w+:\/\/)(.*.com)(\/\w+)/$1$2\/dev\/public_html/ if ($address =~ /.*\/belmark/);

print "Address is: $address";
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/GOiUVH)

Since you're new to regex in Perl, you should start with [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to work for `.net`, `.org` or something else...

Another possible option.

```
my $address = 'http://mail.google.com/belmark';
$address =~ s/(\.(?:net|org|com)).*/$1\/dev\/public_html/ if $address =~ /belmark$/;

print "$address\n";

__OUTPUT__
http://mail.google.com/dev/public_html
```